# is CSS-only, full-width sidebar background possible?

Tags: html, css, width, sidebar

I'm building a fixed width website (using the classic wrapper with margin:auto), but I want the sidebar **background** to extend to the right end of the screen.

So far I've accomplished this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Content area</div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="actual-sidebar">
                Sidebar
            <span class="clearme"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px dashed #fff;
}

#left {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 175px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 325px;
    margin-right: -9999px;
    padding-right: 9999px;
    background: #777;
}

#actual-sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px dotted #f0f;
}
```

​
You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/knjDV/
http://www.spazionegativo.it/layout-test/

Is this kind of "full-width sidebar" possible using **css only**?

In the example above, the actual sidebar width is highlighted by the pink border, and the rest is all padding and negative margin; worked in chrome but IE broke it so I've added *overflow-x: hidden* to fix it.

The problem is, click-dragging to the right will scroll the view even if there's nothing to select, eventually hiding the content. I can't seem to get past this problem.

Is there a fix to the "drag-n-scroll" issue, or an entirely different way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to solve here, the drag-n-scroll issue, it seems to be behaving exactly as it should.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. What I meant is that if you click and drag to the right you'll scroll the view horizontally and eventually hide the content, which is not the behavior I want to achieve.

Comment: That *seems* to be a jsfiddle glitch, do you have a site you can link to?

Comment: I've uploaded it here: http://www.spazionegativo.it/layout-test/

Comment: I think you should go old school with this.  Create an image that is 2000px wide and 1px high. Fill the right 1000px with the color you want.  Now set this image as your background and repeat-y.  If you need it to stop at a certain height you can place the image on an absolutely positioned div and limit its height that way.

Comment: Perhaps I have the wrong idea, But can't you just change the z-index to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add to `#right{ position: fixed;}` that will get rid of the horizontal scrollbar. Is that acceptable?

Comment: You know, I thought this was just wrong. Instead, I've tried it and it works really nice... I had to take the actual sidebar out of the #right div to avoid making it fixed, too. This is as close as I could have gotten, so far. Thank you! Final result here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/knjDV/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 gradients as a background for the body (with the same color as the sidebar) to create the illusion that it extends to the edge of the screen.

```css
.sidebar {
  background: salmon;
}

body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 50%, 0% 50%, color-stop(50%, #fa8072), color-stop(50%, #ffffff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #fa8072 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #fa8072 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #fa8072 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(right, #fa8072 50%, #ffffff 50%);
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CAu3N/)

Comment: I have to say I love your solution, it's very creative! Too bad it doesn't allow the sidebar to have a background image (like a pattern for example). Thanks for answering.